# How to create an array for audio files in android

Tags: android

I am using some audio files, and i want to keep these files in an array . like

```
static int media_ids[]={R.raw.file1,R.raw.file2,R.raw.File2,R.raw.file26};
```

Every thing is working fine, my app is running successfully ,but when I create signed apk . There I got errors related to these audio files.

`Error: cannot find symbol variable raw.`

what I do to remove these errors .

One more thing can I upload debugged apk in google play store.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781884/store-audio-files-in-an-array